# Add Attachments After Filename Statement in SAS

Tags: sas

When sending emails outside of a data step, is it possible to update the attachment list after the filename statement?

Within a Data step you can use the !EM_ATTACH! directive to change the attachments on the fly, but that doesn't appear to work outside of a data step.

```
filename    outbox email
                    to          = &emailToAddress
                    cc          = &emailCCAddress
                    from        = &emailFromAddress
                    replyto = &emailReplyToAddress
                    sender  = &emailSender
                    type        = 'text/html'
                    subject = &subject
                    ;
ods listing close;

ods html
        body=outbox
        rs=none
        style=Dove;

/* Do something here that figures out what needs to be attached */

Proc Print Data=somedataset;
Run;

/* Add attachment here */

ods html close;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to use email directives outside a data step. Also, based on a bit of my own testing, it appears that directives can only modify email parameters within the data step where they are used - if you try to change attachments using a directives in a data step and cancel sending via `!EM_ABORT!`, then re-use the same fileref for ods output, the email will be sent using the parameters from the original filename statement.

Try saving your `ods html` output to a separate html file, and then include that as an attachment.